# Its possible to compile a php script and the mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script who access a MySQL database, all running in my server. I know how to compile php scripts in order to generate a .exe program, but this is the first time I got a php script that uses a MySQL, and I dont know how to compile the entire think. I dont want the .exe to use a remote mysql because I need to use it offline.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What are you using to create the .exe files? Normally the compilers need to support certain database extensions as well for this to work, so it's worth to share. Next to that you might look for a file-based database like sqlite.

Comment: PHP itself just access mysql database via remote/socket connections and never integrate it itself. You may think about SQLite, if you are looking for an embedded dbms.

Comment: @KingCrunch: Actually there is pipes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use PDO you might just switch to SQLite on the fly.

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible to embed a MySQL server in a compiled PHP script. The best you will be able to do is either replace MySQL with something like SQLite (not sure how feasible that will be) or build an installer that ships MySQL and the appropriate database tables (much more feasible).